# Certificate exception while installing another Sitecore 9 instance on same machine

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-install-framework

Installing 9.0.0 on a machine already having 9.0.1. Getting below Cert exception:

```
PS>TerminatingError(New-SelfSignedCertificate): "CertEnroll::CSignerCertificate::Initialize: Cannot find object or property. 0x80092004 (-2146885628 CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND)"
>> TerminatingError(New-SelfSignedCertificate): "CertEnroll::CSignerCertificate::Initialize: Cannot find object or property. 0x80092004 (-2146885628 CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND)"
>> TerminatingError(New-SelfSignedCertificate): "CertEnroll::CSignerCertificate::Initialize: Cannot find object or property. 0x80092004 (-2146885628 CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND)"
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : CertEnroll::CSignerCertificate::Initialize: Cannot find object or property. 0x80092004 (-2146885628 CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND) (edited)
```

Googled and found few relevant blog post like:

https://learnsitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2018/06/28/install-sitecoreconfiguration-the-certificate-does-not-have-a-property-that-references-a-private-key/

As suggested, from MMC and C Drive already removed the certificate having a prefix which I am passing in `$prefix` parameter. But I can not delete `DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreFundamentalRoot` and `DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert` as my previous 9.0.1 instance is using there certs.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Richard Dzien came to rescue on SIF Slack Channel.

If you want to keep the old SC9 install then when you install another SC9 instance make sure you set an alternative `RootCertFileName` parameter value in the json or the script you call it with.

If using the example script add `IdentityServerCertificates_RootCertFileName = "AlternativeRootName"` to the hashtable and also `XConnectCertificates_RootCertFileName = "AlternativeRootName"` to the hashtable if you are using the XP0 or XP1 examples. The easiest way is just to edit the `createcert.json` and change the `defaultvalue` for `RootCerFileName` (Line#15) though.

As a quick workaround, I changed the `RootCerFileName` in `createcert.json` file, tried reinstalling and everything went well.